# How can I translate this polling into Timer without checking every minute if user is expired?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I have service in which in ctor i defined async timer which is checking every 45 second if there is expired users or they are already confirmed their account: https://gist.github.com/Taifunov/85a7931d74fe982237df7503e9fc0216

Or how to do it in efficient way to not disturb db so often?

Comment: Extending the polling time?

Comment: It all depends on how optimized your queries are.